# Shuffling a list while keeping order relative to related elements

Tags: python, sorting, random

I'm looking to shuffle a list of the elements a1, ... a6, ... e1, ..., e6

while keeping two rules:

if I loop though the list and filter out a specific letter or number it should be in order:

a1, a2, a3... or a1, b1, c1 ...

How can I shuffle the list keeping these rules? Is there a python library. for such a task?

Here's an example of a shuffle that would fit the criteria:

a1, b1, a2, b2, c1, a3, d1, c2, d2, e1, a4, b3, c3, d3, b4, d4, c4, a5, e2, d5, e3, c5, a6, b5, e4, a7, b6, c6, b7, d6, e5, e6, c7, d7, e7

```
for each in shuffled:
    if each[1]=='1':
        print(each)
```

yields: a1, b1, c1, d1, e1.

The problem isn't sorting them, it's generating the random list in the first place.

Comment: Do you want the final order to be randomly generated (but obeying the two rules)? Also it isn't clear what order you want the data sorted in "... b4, d4, c4 ..." seems to break the rules you specify.

Comment: Yes, it should be a random list that when iterate though and filtered, they the filtered elements are ordered relative to each other. For example if I iterate though with 

for each in shuffled:
    if each[1]=='1':
        print(each)

I then get a1, b1, c1, d1, e1 .... not b1, a1 or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there are libraries doing this.
There is a simple solution:

First, split the list to sublists in which elements are in order:

```
x = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7'],
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7'],
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7'],
 ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7'],
 ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7']]
```

Then pop the first element of a randomly selected sublist.

```
from random import shuffle
select = list(range(5))*7 
shuffle(select) 
[x[idx].pop(0) for idx in select]
```

The result is (depends on your shuffle result):

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'e1', 'c2', 'e2', 'd1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'd2', 'e3', 'b3', 'a4', 'b4', 'a5', 'd3', 'a6', 'e4', 'd4', 'e5', 'd5', 'a7', 'e6', 'd6', 'b5', 'e7', 'b6', 'd7', 'c7', 'b7']
```